# What's the difference between $_POST, $_GET, and $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, global-variables

I am bit confused about these super global variable (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, and `$_REQUEST`) in PHP. In which scenario do I need to use these variables in PHP, and what are the main differences these three stand for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get

Comment: Or the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - always a great resource ;-)

Comment: It would be a good idea to never use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: hi @suraj thanks for your reply, I tried that link, but it not included the request variable

Comment: that is regarding $GET and $POST in general with respect to http.. $_REQUEST as the answer will contain request values irrespective of type of request..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All three are 'superglobal' or automatic global, arrays.

**$_POST** is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via HTTP request body, in case it was encoded using either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data Content-Type. The most familiar way to have this array filled is to send an HTML form with POST method.

You need to use this array to process an HTML form configured with method="POST".

**$_GET** is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the query string (sometimes called URL parameters). The most familiar way to have this array filled is to send an HTML form with GET method.

You need to use this array to get access to variables from query string, regardless of method used.

**$_REQUEST** is an associative array that combines data from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE (depending on [`request_order=`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order))

It is advised to avoid using this array at all, and use specific arrays instead.

> In which scenario do I need to use these variables in PHP

I suppose you are asking about HTTP methods, not arrays (which merely reflect the method used).

- GET method should be used when the server state is not changed by request. In other words, when the data you are sending will be used to retrieve some information but won't be stored on the server.
- POST method should be used otherwise - i.e. when you need to store the data sent on the server or change its state somehow (for example to make it know you are an authorized user with correct login and password)

Comment: `$_COOKIE` shouldn't be stroken over. Either delete it or specify for which versions of PHP it is valid for (or some other explanation, whatever is true).

Comment: they are all "superglobals". Full list: `$GLOBALS, $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION, $_REQUEST, $_ENV` as documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Something seems wrong with this answer, it says that "$_REQUEST (...) by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST". It contains itself? Other answers seem to imply that it should read "$_COOKIE" and not "$_REQUEST" in the end. But perhaps somebody more sure of this can edit the answer instead of me.

Answer (score 11):

Difference is:

- $_GET retrieves variables from the query string, or your URL.
- $_POST retrieves variables from the request body, in case it was encoded using either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data encoding.
- $_REQUEST is a merging of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE where order of overriding values with same keys is defined in PHP configuration.

Comment: Actually the `$_REQUEST` behaviour is determined by the `request_order` and `variables_order ` configuration directives.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` Also includes values in the `$_COOKIE` super global ;)
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Finally I think you are answering my question. If I have a POST [name] and a GET[name] if I did a REQUEST [name] it would = POST [name] - correct (out with a `request_order`)? I am beginning to think REQUEST ain't that useful. When would u use it?

Comment: Can you update your answer to qualify "where $_POST overrides $_GET" (as other comments have alluded to)?

Comment: actually, "The default php.ini on your system as of in PHP 5.3.0 may exclude cookies from `$_REQUEST`." from a comment here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 methods to send HTML form data from 1 Page to another or HTML page to server side (In PHP).

1. `POST`

It is a method in which data gets sent using packet which is not visible to any user on web-browser. it is secured compared to GET method.

2. `GET`

It is a method in which data gets sent with URL which is visible to user in address-bar of any web-browser. So, it’s not secure as POST method.

Now, There are total three super global variables to catch this data in PHP.

1. `$_POST`: It can catch the data which is sent using POST method.
2. `$_GET`: It can catch the data which is sent using GET method.
3. `$_REQUEST`: It can catch the data which is sent using both POST & GET methods.

Also with `$_GET` superglobal variable can collect data sent in the URL from submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to know better, please visit *[GET vs. POST](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests)*:

> 1) Both `$_GET` and `$_POST` create an array e.g. `array( key => value, key2 => value2, key3 => value3, ...)`. This array holds key/value pairs, where keys are the names of the form controls and values are the input data from the user.
>
> 2) Both `GET` and `POST` are treated as `$_GET` and `$_POST`. These are superglobals, which means that they are always accessible, regardless of scope - and you can access them from any function, class or file without having to do anything special.
>
> 3) `$_GET` is an array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.
>
> 4) `$_POST` is an array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
>
> ---- whereas `$_REQUEST` contains `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` .

Answer (score -1):

$GET : When you use GET method, your paramethers and requests will appear on URL adress
`$POST:` If you use POST method, doesnt

Also POST methods safer than GET methods

Answer (score -2):

$_POST hides the variables/values (they cannot be seen), whereas $_GET shows them!
If the values include passwords or other sensible info, it's advisable to use $_POST.

Comment: You are confusing php arrays with the way HTML forms handled by browser. Also, POST method doesn't actually hide anything.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).